# Why do we need Intel SSD Toolbox for TRIM?

Tags: ssd, trim

Why does Intel SSD Toolbox need to schedule a TRIM on a daily or weekly basis if the underlying SSD supports the TRIM command? Shouldn't the drive TRIM in real-time without this tool? Is this tool made for users whose motherboard and/or operating-system block the TRIM command from reaching the SSD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is for operating systems that do not themselves support TRIM, like XP and Vista, who don't send the TRIM command. With Windows 7 windows itself sends the TRIM command every time something is deleted.

If something is blocking the TRIM command (like the drive being in an RAID array) this Toolbox will not overcome that.

Comment: According to http://www.intel.com/design/flash/nand/mainstream/index.htm "The Intel SSD Optimizer [...] is specifically designed to run with Microsoft Windows 7." Is this just some marketing talk or does it contradict what you wrote?

Comment: @Gili - The Optimizer is not only for running TRIM.  Have you actually used it?

Comment: @Sinrai, yes I've used it but as far as I can tell all it does is TRIM. What makes you believe it does anything else?

Comment: Ah! According to http://download.intel.com/support/ssdc/hpssd/sb/intel_ssd_toolbox_fqa.pdf Question #11 you don't need to use the SSD Optimizer if you're using Windows 7 with Microsoft's AHCI driver.

Comment: @Gili - The other functions available make me think it does anything else?  It has secure erase, passes through SMART data, etc...

Comment: Er, I misspoke slightly - the OPTIMIZER is just for TRIM.  The TOOLBOX, however, is not.  It has, uh, other tools. :)