# Is WesternDigital Dashboard needed to trim a SSD?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, trim

Based on this question [Why do we need Intel SSD Toolbox for TRIM?](https://superuser.com/questions/266956/why-do-we-need-intel-ssd-toolbox-for-trim) it seems that there is no need to use vendor's application to trim.

But although I'm sure Windows 10 trim is not disabled but in WD Dashboard there is a checkbox "enable trim" which is not checked so now I'm not sure what is the real status of trim.

My way to check trim is from online:

```
fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

the result is "0(disabled)", which means trim is enabled. I'm not sure whether this is enough and why there isn't an UI to show information as important as this.

Another question is will windows do trim when I delete a whole partition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checkbox in the WD software may well be to have that software manually initiate a TRIM on a regular basis.

If TRIM is indeed enabled in Windows then it will be run on a schedule as the Disk Optimisation tool (the same tool that occasionally defragments HDDs) runs. Instead of defragmentation the tool will simply TRIM SSDs.

If you go to your disk properties and then Disk Optimisation you will see what type of disk it is and what it will do:

[image: optimise vs defrag]

You'll notice that it shows "optimise" rather than "defragment" for SSDs.

When you click "optimise" for a drive it will say "25% trimmed" and so on instead of "xx% defragmented". The process of TRIMming should not take particularly long.

The image came from [NextOfWindows](https://www.nextofwindows.com/windows-10-treats-ssds-extremely-well-with-improved-management-features), that page also describes how to get to that tool.

Your command shows that TRIM should already be enabled.

Comment: While it's actually running, the status will change from "OK" to "Trimming".

Comment: @MichaelHampton I was going to mention that it changes status to something that distinctly implies that it was not defragmenting and was in fact doing a TRIM, but I wasn't at a machine I could check on. Adding now.

Comment: You need to enable disk optimization, too, in my case all optimization was disabled to get rid of 100% disk utilization, and the status is "never". Now I enable optimization only on SSD and run trim manually once. The process only taks several seconds. After this WD Dashboard still says it is never trimed. So the trim status seems to only log the history of trim run from that software.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify
```

Gave as result "0  (Disabled)", which means that the disabling is disabled,
or in other words, that TRIM is **enabled**. Yes, this is confusing.

When trying it on my computer I get:

`NTFS DisableDeleteNotify = 0 (Disabled)`  (TRIM support enabled for SSDs with NTFS)
`ReFS DisableDeleteNotify = 0 (Disabled)`  (TRIM support enabled for SSDs with ReFS)

Comment: This answer is entirely irrelevant to the question (the OP clearly knew that `DisableDeleteNotify = 0 (Disabled)` means TRIM enabled).